# Change standard address format on Magento Frontend

Tags: magento

I want to change Magento's standard address format on the customer address page. How can I do that?

For those who don't know the address format, it is the method in wich we write the address. For example, the english format for France is this:

```
Addressee (Natural person/Organization)
More detailed description of addressee (optional)
Housenumber + Streetname
Postal code + uppercase town
Country (if other than France)
```

The address format for the USA is this:

```
Name of address
Street number and name
Name of town, State abbreviation + ZIP code
(typical handwritten format)
```

You can [read more at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_%28geography%29). Thanks a lot.

Comment: please be more specific. What is current address format, what sort of address you want etc.

Comment: downwoted "impossible to answer" type question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking the address formats are contained in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/config.xml look for some markup like this:

...

```
<default>
  <customer>
    <address_formats> 
     <text><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
{{var country}}
T: {{var telephone}}
{{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}}]]></text>
    </address_templates>
  </customer>
</default>
```

...

Comment: How to change this adress format in New Magento Order Confirmation Email ?

Comment: In the address_templates element you'll see entries for text, html, pdf, and oneline. The new order emails typically use the html format so you may need to update that one as well.

Comment: Just the perfect solution for my needs.

Answer (score 30):

It seems that the config.xml file is no longer used (or just to load the default values into the database).

Go to:

> System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration and scroll down to Address Templates.

There you find the same code as in the XML file.

Answer (score 4):

Magento Render Address as  it is defined in magento admin Configuration. You can manage address format by changing address template.

Go to System/Configuration/Customer Configuration/Address Template/Html/
Edit the content as you wish to show.

Similarly you can edit PDF template for changing the pdf view of address.

Comment: Thank you, but that's only in the new Magento versions :)

Answer (score 3):

I have create module for define multiple address format base on county :

Below is simple way to create it.

Create admin module for insert update 'directory_country_format' table.

rewrite Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default class in you module.

override below function

```
public function getFormat(Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract $address=null)
{
    $countryFormat = is_null($address) ? parent::getFormat($address) :       
     $address->getCountryModel()->getFormat($this->getType()->getCode());
     if (is_object($countryFormat)) {
          $cFormat = $countryFormat->getFormat();
      }

    $format = $countryFormat ?   
    (!empty($cFormat)?$cFormat:$this->getType()->getDefaultFormat()) : 
    $this->getType()->getDefaultFormat();
    return $format;
}
```

Here is my module which help you for define address formats base on customer country.

http://magentosolution.com/index.php/2014/08/27/magento-address-formats-base-of-country/